# docker container exits immediately after run [mosquitto broken container]

Tags: linux, docker, debian, containers, mosquitto

hello i have a problem with docker, recently i make dockerfile for create a image of "mosquitto-mqtt" to make my own broken mqtt with ssl protection. i build dockerfile all is good, i don't have a problem but if i run a new container with " docker run -itd --name broken ce69ee4b2f4e" a container run and exit automaticly, and if a check log all is good "[ ok .] Starting network daemon:: mosquitto.". i don't have why ? check my dockerfile. i need help to solve it, thanks you

```
#Download base image debian
FROM debian:latest

#Update system
RUN apt-get update -y

#Install Wget and gnup2
RUN apt-get install wget -y && apt-get install gnupg2 -y

#Download and add key
RUN wget http://repo.mosquitto.org/debian/mosquitto-repo.gpg.key
RUN apt-key add mosquitto-repo.gpg.key
RUN rm mosquitto-repo.gpg.key

## append apt mirror for debian
RUN echo "# mirror" >> /etc/apt/source.list
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mosquitto.org/debian stretch main" >> /etc/apt/source.list

#Update and upgrade system
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y

#install mosquitto
RUN apt-get install mosquitto -y

#Copy file configuration
COPY mosquitto.conf /etc/mosquitto

#Copy certificate folder
COPY certs/mosquitto-ca.crt /etc/mosquitto/certs
COPY certs/mosquitto-server.crt /etc/mosquitto/certs
COPY certs/mosquitto-server.key /etc/mosquitto/certs

#Run command
ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/init.d/mosquitto", "start"]
```

log print

```
[ ok .] Starting network daemon:: mosquitto.
```

docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
d00bd23ae2d6        ce69ee4b2f4e              "/etc/init.d/mosquit…"   9 minutes ago       Exited (0) 9 minutes ago                       broken
```

Comment: Did you check logs? Have you tried entering interactively to the container an execute teh entrypoint manually?

Comment: yes i check log, he print "[ ok .] Starting network daemon:: mosquitto." and if i try to entry into container he print "[ ok .] Starting network daemon:: mosquitto." and exit automaticly

Answer (score 1):

Containers are a wrapper around a process, and when that process exits, the container exits. In this case:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/init.d/mosquitto", "start"]
```

That process is `/etc/init.d/mosquitto` which almost certainly runs, spawns a daemon in the background, and exits (standard for anything in init.d). You should instead run mosquito directly with foreground options if available.

If that's some possible, something like supervisord would be a less than optimal fallback, with the ability to watch a background daemon.

And if neither of those work, you can run your command from a script that ends with a `tail -f /dev/null`, but that would be the worst option since you ignore any errors.

Comment: thanks you @BMitch, it try option 1,  i gone to Dockerfile of official github repository of "Eclipse-mosquitto" and i found the solution to run container without exit automaticly, it just to add -c on mosquitto command and specify configuration file "ENTRYPOINT ["mosquitto", "-c", "/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf"]". thanks

Comment: Note that `/etc/init.d/mosquitto` and `mosquitto` aren't the same command, and that's a good thing in this case.

Comment: Yeah! All right, i discover it when i build dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

it works ! i found the solution, it just need to add "-C" on command and specify directory

this is a good method

```
ENTRYPOINT ["mosquitto", "-c", "/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf"]
```

thanks all to help Me!